# Pymongo: update document only if value of a field matches a provided value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to update a document based on the condition that the value of a field in that document matches a value that I provide?

I can easily do this in two steps but was wondering if there was a way to do it in a single call to MongoAtlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a single step execution. You don't need two steps.

[Reference](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateOne)

And Python implementation is same syntax as plain queries.

```
db.collection.update_one({
  filter condition goes here
},{
  '$set': {
    update fields goes here
  }
}, upsert=False) //Options
```